# How to get Firebase user generated token and use in ref path?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’ve been trying for many days get Firebase user generated token for use in my ref path, but I get this console error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null"** I read [firebase web docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) about this,tried other methods( *getIdToken* and etc. ) but nothing help me.I need only display end fields in structure like "name". If it possible please anyone help me or give advice. Because of this problem, I can’t continue the project :(

My Database structure.[Please check this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxeNx.jpg)

Head scripts

```
<head>
    <title>Retrieve data</title>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" /> 
</head>
```

My code

```
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Name:</th>
 </table> 

<script>

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var database = firebase.database();

    //Date function start
    function getDateId(dt){
    var date = new Date(dt);
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    if (currentMonth < 10) { currentMonth = 1 + currentMonth};
    if (currentMonth < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth};
    if (currentDate < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentDate};
    return `Date${currentDate}${currentMonth}${date.getFullYear()}` 
    }

    var inputDate = new Date();
    var dateId = getDateId(inputDate).toString(); // End Date function

    /// console.log(dateId) for test

    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid().toString(); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null . What is mean ?

    database.ref('/Notes/' +userId).child(dateId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
               content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });


</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, by the time your `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid()` runs, the user hasn't been initialized yet. This is not uncommon, since Firebase needs to check with the server in order to restore user state on a page load.

The proper way to deal with this is to [use an `onAuthStateChange()` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to detect when the user has been restored:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    database.ref('/Notes/' +user.uid).child(dateId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
               content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
  }
});
```